# HTML Different link type Question

Tags: html

What is the difference between? Thank you.

```
<img src="images/file.jpg"></img>

between

<img src="/images/file.jpg"></img>

between

<img src="./images/file.jpg"></img>

between

<img src="../images/file.jpg"></img>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to learn about [relative and absolute paths](http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/a/aa040502a.htm).

Here are my explanations for your examples, but you realy should read the link in order to understand the concepts.

If the base URL is "http://example.com/resources/" then:

```
<img src="images/file.jpg"></img>
```

Will get:

```
http://example.com/resources/images/file.jpg
```

It simply adds the src url to the base URL.

---

```
<img src="/images/file.jpg"></img>
```

Will get:

```
http://example.com/images/file.jpg
```

Bacuse the image URL is rooted (starts with `/`) it uses the domain and adds the image src to the domain.

---

```
<img src="./images/file.jpg"></img>
```

Will get:

```
http://example.com/resource/images/file.jpg
```

In this case, it uses the relative path for the current directory (`.`), which is the base directory (resources).

---

```
<img src="../images/file.jpg"></img>
```

Will get:

```
http://example.com/images/file.jpg
```

In this case, it uses the relative path for the parent directory (`..`), which makes it go up a directory and then add the rest of the path.

Comment: so <img src="./images/file.jpg"> and <img src="images/file.jpg"> are functionally the same, right?

Answer (score 0):

The first, third and last ones are relative to the current path. In the last one, `..` is the parent folder, which means you essentially ascend one level in the hierarchy, and in the second one `.` is the current folder, making the URI equivalent to the first one. The second one is relative to the root, since it starts with `/`. Read more about URIs in the [HTML4 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/intro/intro.html#h-2.1), or in general about [Unix-style paths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29#Unix_style).

Thus, if you're at `website.com/folder/folder/index.html`, the four URIs would be equivalent to this:

```
website.com/folder/folder/images/file.jpg
website.com/images/file.jpg
website.com/folder/folder/images/file.jpg
website.com/folder/images/file.jpg
```

Comment: No, they're all relative. That is, the user agent will add information in order to create an absolute URI so it can request the resource. The difference is in what they're relative *to*. The first is relative to the current file (and is for all intents and purposes equivalent to the third, "./..."), the second relative to the server root, the third to the current directory and the fourth to the parent directory. A good argument can be made for root-relative links being a best practice for all local links, since it will not break if the host doc moves. An absolute URI includes the protocol.

Comment: Good point. However, I disagree with the statement that the last one is relative to its parent — it is relative to the current folder, except that the special folder `..` refers to the parent folder.